# How to sort in EF parents by number of children of children of children?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have **Team**s of **Coder**s of **Project**s of **Task**s.

How do I effectively sort **Team**s by number of **Task**s in Entity Framework using method syntax and Code First approach (probably without loading whole collection contents of children of children, I need sort only)?

```
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CTeam> Teams { get; set; }
    // ...etc
}
```

```
[Table("Team")]
public class CTeam
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Coders")]
    public virtual ICollection<CCoder> Coders { get; set; }
}



[Table("Coder")]
public class CCoder
{

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(128)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CProject> Projects { get; set; }

    public int TeamID { get; set; }
    public virtual CTeam Team { get; set; }
}

//  CProject and CTask similarly
```

Optionally, if you could give a hint how raw SQL should look like for this, this would help too. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

In a project with relationships `Builder -> NewBuildingObject -> NewBuildingHouse -> NewBuildingLayout`

For viewer's convinience, *Teodor Ivanov*'s answer:

```
context.Teams
.OrderBy(x => x.Coders
   .SelectMany(y => y.Projects)
   .SelectMany(y => y.Tasks)
   .Count());
```

made EF to generate this code:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM   [dbo].[NewBuildingObject] AS [Extent2]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[NewBuildingHouse] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[ID] = [Extent3].[ObjectID]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[NewBuildingLayout] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent4].[HouseID]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[BuilderID]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Builder] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

and *Yacoub Massad*'s answer:

```
var teams = context.Teams
    .OrderBy(team =>
        team.Coders.SelectMany(coder =>
            coder.Projects.SelectMany(project => project.Tasks)).Count());
```

made this code:

```
SELECT 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[Title] AS [Title]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM  [dbo].[NewBuildingObject] AS [Extent2]
            INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent3].[ObjectID] AS [ObjectID]
                FROM  [dbo].[NewBuildingHouse] AS [Extent3]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[NewBuildingLayout] AS [Extent4] ON [Extent3].[ID] = [Extent4].[HouseID] ) AS [Join1] ON [Extent2].[ID] = [Join1].[ObjectID]
            WHERE [Extent1].[ID] = [Extent2].[BuilderID]) AS [C1]
        FROM [dbo].[Builder] AS [Extent1]
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[C1] ASC
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like

```
context.Teams
.OrderBy(x => x.Coders
   .SelectMany(y => y.Projects)
   .SelectMany(y => y.Tasks)
   .Count());
```

Comment: Thank you! Your solution is working great. I accept this answer as earliest one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `SelectMany` like this:

```
var teams = context.Teams
    .OrderBy(team =>
        team.Coders.SelectMany(coder =>
            coder.Projects.SelectMany(project => project.Tasks)).Count());
```